# What is the difference between type and xtype in system views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

There are several columns in many of the system views that have the 'x' prefix, does anyone know what this is suppose to signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely is only for **backward compatibility** purposes.

- type is an older column kept for compatibility with previous versions
- xtype is more complete and is the one that should be used

See [sys.sysobjects (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) for a list of differences.

Answer (score 0):

`xtype` for `UNIQUE CONTRAINT` and `PRIMARY KEY` will be `UQ` and `PK`, respectively, while `type` if both of them is `K`.

That's the only difference I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it was sybase compatibility

SQL Server started life as a fork of sybase, and it had just the 'type' column

When Microsoft extended the types they added a new column 'xtype'

You can see soem types don't have a 'type' with

select name, xtype, type from master..systypes

So in general I think you should use the 'xtype' column, and ignore the 'type' column